# requiring msvcr80.dll and msvcr80d.dll in the same dll?

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies

how can it be that a dll that i build here (in debug mode) tries to load msvcr80.dll and msvcr80d.dll ... i assume this leads then to a conflict as it can resolve the same symbols twice ...

i have no idea why the dependency to msvcr80.dll comes in. according to dependency walker ouput the dependency comes directly from my dll and not via another dll ...

could this be a problem of build settings of my debug build?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't lead to big conflicts, as all symbols are implicitly scoped by the DLL they're exported from. E.g. you can have `msvcr80.dll::printf` and `msvcr80d.dll::printf` in parallel. But even though you might not have _conflicts_, you can still have other problems. E.g. mixing `msvcr80.dll::malloc` and `msvcr80d.dll::free`

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by one of the dlls you are liked with is linked in release mode
so they load msvcr80.dll while you are loading msvcr80d.dll.

And yes, this may cause a problem

> could this be a problem of build settings of my debug build?

Yes